# If every polynomial in $F[x]$ splits then there exists no nontrivial algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Im trying to prove the statement of the title:

If every polynomial in $F[x]$ splits then $F$ has no nontrivial algebraic extension

I was thinking about arguing as follows: if there existed an algebraic extension $K=F(\alpha)$ then $\alpha$ would have to be transcendental. But 
i)I don't know if this would prove the claim ii)I don't even know how to continue along that line of reasoning

Comment: That's an oxymoron: an algebraic extension cannot be generated by a transcendental element.

Comment: Said another way, "algebraic extension" means every element is algebraic, (in particular $\alpha$.) Trancendental means "not algebraic."

Comment: yeah, sorry i meant to say it would be proof by contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be an algebraic extension of $F$ and let $\alpha \in E$.

Then $F(\alpha) \cong F[x]/(f(x))$, where $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Since $f$ is irreducible, it must have degree $1$ and so $\alpha \in F$.

Thus $E \subseteq F$ and so $E=F$.